# Analog of spring @Controller annotation in Java config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring DI I love to use @Bean with factory method in @Configuration class instead of using @Component annotation explicitly. Is there a way to do the same with @Controller annotation for Spring Web? In another words, could I declare controller via factory method in some @Configuration class instead of explicit annotation?

Comment: Why down vote? Why no comment? I would also be interested if there is a different way to register controllers except for @Controller annotation and component scanning.

Comment: Just upvote it then :)

Comment: I do not like down votes without a comment. How can we learn from our mistakes then? Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not possible since @Controller can only be placed on types. But more important are the methods. I assume you have multiple methods with @RequestMethod annotations. You can place as much methods as you like in this controller with differnet paths. Which should end up in around the same thing as you want?

Comment: Component annotation is not allowed for methods as well, but Bean annotation does the things right. What I want is controller modularity and replaceability. Consider I want to swap controller for another environment.  It should have the same paths and methods, but another logic inside. With Bean annotations it's easy - I simply use either another Configuration to init spring or Profile mechanism. But how to do achieve it with controllers? Ofcourse I could create a bean with logic and delegae controller methods to it, but I believe there should be a more convenient way to do it.

Comment: You can put the Profile annotation also on classes annotated with @Controller to exclude them from the application context.

Comment: And is it possible without Profiles, just using raw Configuration classes?

Comment: There's not just one approach how you can accomplish this. One would be to put all controllers of one profile in a specific package and extend the component scan in the configuration class to that package.

Comment: I see, but what I like about Configuration class approach is that all the information about your beans is centralized and compacted in a list of factory methods which is easy to read and change. Yes I understand that you can set the package to scan, but the problem is - you have to navigate to that package and manipulate files there. And what if you want a different impl - you have to copy old impl to another package just not to loose it and copy new impl back? As for me, it's not very handy.